# Load information to a div based on a click from another div

Tags: php, ajax

This is probably terribly simple. I have done something similar to this when the information was being passed to a different page.
Basically... I have a div with a dynamically generated list of objects.

```
<li><a href="#" id="<?= trim($array['City']) ?>" onclick="loadZipCodes('<?= (trim($array['City'])) ?>')"><?= $array['City'] ?></a></li>
```

All of the code already exists to load the zip codes for a given city, so in PHP (in this case)

```
$locations = new ProjectsLocationsArrays();
$zipcodes = $locations->array_zips($array['City']);
```

At present, everything runs off of query strings... ?city=aaa&zip=123, seems sloppy to me. I would like to use AJAX. Once the cities are loaded, how do I load the zips into an existing div on the page, fired by a click on one of the city anchors.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have jQuery something like this should work

```
function loadZipCodes(city){
    $.ajax({
      url: "pagethatgivesarrayofzipcodes.php",
      method: "POST",
      data : {'city': city}
    }).done(function(data) {
      $(.zip-div).html(data);
    });
}
```

Where pagethatgivesarrayofzipcodes.php takes a $_POST['city'] containing the city info and returns either HTML or a a Javascript array of ZIP codes.

Comment: That makes sense... but what if I don't want to leave the page. Can I post to the current page and just check for postback or something (I might be confusing myself) - I will give it a go. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: NEVERMIND - I see it clear now. Thank you!